# Proper command to convert m3u8 to mp4

Tags: video

I found these various commands and am confused why they're so different from each other:

- [m3u8 stream to mp4 using ffmpeg - GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/tzmartin/fb1f4a8e95ef5fb79596bd4719671b5d)

  ```
  ffmpeg -i "http://url/in.m3u8" -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vcodec copy -c copy -crf 50 out.mp4
  ```
- [Converting an HLS (m3u8) to MP4 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33111765/1247334)

  ```
  ffmpeg -i http://url/in.m3u8 -acodec copy -vcodec copy out.mp4
  ffmpeg -i http://url/in.m3u8 -acodec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vcodec copy out.mp4
  ```
- [FFMPEG mp4 from http live streaming m3u8 file? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32537953/1247334)

  ```
  ffmpeg -i http://url/in.m3u8 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc out.mp4
  ffmpeg -i http://url/in.m3u8 -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -t <time> out.mp4
  ```
- [Download or convert M3U8 stream to MP4 - FFmpeg Support Forum](https://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2835)

  ```
  ffmpeg -i "http://url/in.m3u8" -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mp4  C:\LOCATION-NAME
  ```
- [How do I download the following m3u8 url? - VideoHelp Forum](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/359319-How-do-I-download-the-following-m3u8-url)

  ```
  ffmpeg -i "http://url/in.m3u8" -c copy out.mkv
  ffmpeg -i "http://url/in.m3u8" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc out.mkv
  ```

1. **What are the proper bits to put in this command and in what order?**
2. **Does the URL need to be in quotes?**
3. **Where in my system will it save this "out.mp4"?**

In case anybody wants to know, I'm trying to extract the main video on this page:
http://abc13.com/science/meet-female-scientists-thriving-in-male-dominated-field/2040879

In the code for that page I found this m3u8 url:
http://content.uplynk.com/ext/1efe3bfc4d1e4b5db5e5085a535b510b/052617-ewn-4pm-women-in-science-vid_web.m3u8

I went ahead and tried one of the above, just to see what would happen. It did give me an mp4 of the video, but the audio/video was out of sync pretty badly. Here's the command I used:

```
ffmpeg -i http://content.uplynk.com/ext/1efe3bfc4d1e4b5db5e5085a535b510b/052617-ewn-4pm-women-in-science-vid_web.m3u8 -acodec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vcodec copy out.mp4
```

5. **so, in addition to the 4 questions above, is there a way to get the a/v to stay in sync?**

Comment: Reading the manual would be a good starting point.

Comment: well, have you seen that manual?! holy cow it's long & confusing. i'm a lay-person, not a programmer; just trying to get a news video of my sister. am hoping a kind soul will help with this single task that is not in my field of expertise. and yes, i did try to read the manual & was just too lost.

Comment: OK, you get a +1 for effort. I don't have ffmpeg installed on this machine, will try later to find one that does.