# Convert m3u8 to mp4 on mac

Tags: file-conversion, streaming, vlc

I'm trying to convert m3u8 to mp4 on a Mac.

I have followed the instructions of a person who does it using VLC in Windows, however I can not find the option in the mac version.

1. Media -> Open Network Stream...
2. Enter a Network URL
3. Play Submenu (missing on a Mac) -> Convert
4. Set Destination File -> Start
5. Ok! File Downloaded and converted.

[image: Screenshot VLC on Mac vs VLC Windows]

Comment: Not directly an answer, but you can find alternative ways to accomplish this in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285635/proper-command-to-convert-m3u8-to-mp4.